# Python : Overriding a method from a third-party module (Tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-module

In Tkinter we are having few functions from module `tkSimpleDialog` .

```
from Tkinter import  *
import tkSimpleDialog

def t():
    root = Tk()
    f = tkSimpleDialog.askinteger("Add New User","Enter card Number")
    print f;
    mainloop()
t()
```

Above code snippet prompt for input.I need  to write my own function for error handling (when user click `OK`  and doesn't enter any thing or invalid input ) and some other properties like resizing , height , width e.t.c. of dialog box .

How to override function e.g. ok ?

Answer (score 2):

You could make your own dialog class that inherits from `tkSimpleDialog`. This way you could override any of the class' core methods. Classic OOP and extension to the rescue.

Check this documentation out for a tutorial: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Another one: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm

You could take a look at tkSimpleDialog.py source to see the available class methods and see which ones you can extend. Quicker way is to do `dir(tkSimpleDialog)` after you have imported it, to see all its methods, properties and classes.

Always remember, if something is a class, there exists an opportunity to extend it into your own!

All the best.

Comment: Actually firstly i checked tkSimpleDialog.py file then i asked this question . I also has visited site that you linked . I would like to inherit features using this file.

Comment: Your code doesnt reflect the fact that you went through that tutorial. Your code is not trying to inherit any class. If you want to customize some functionality of a class, you need to inherit it and override the methods you want to customize. Just check out the section called "Creating a simple dialog, revisited" from the first link.

Comment: If you look at Ok function in that module then you will find that this is private to the module .

Comment: You must override `validate()` if you just want to do your own validation. If you want to add a custom action, then override `apply()`. Leave `ok()` untouched, as it calls validate first and then apply method. What do you want to do exactly